# How can I tell if something is a Perl 6 container?

Tags: containers, raku

I don't have no useful reason for knowing this, but I was wondering if I had a name such as `$x`, if that was a scalar variable (mutable thingy) or merely the name for something (immutable thingy). I'm not trying to accomplish anything; this is curiosity.

I was playing around with something like this:

```
my @a  = 'a', ('b', 'c' );
my @b  = 'd', 'e', 'f', @a;

my @ab = @a, @b, ( 1, 2 );

for @ab {
    put "name: {.^name} VAR: { .VAR.^name }";
    when .VAR.can('FETCH') { put "Container: $_" }
    when .VAR.can('STORE') { put "Container: $_" }
    when Scalar            { put "Scalar container: $_" }
    when Array             { put "Array Container: $_" }
    default                { put "Object: $_"    }
    }
```

I get:

```
name: Array VAR: Scalar
Array Container: a b c
name: Array VAR: Scalar
Array Container: d e f a b c
name: List VAR: Scalar
Object: 1 2
```

I can see that I can match the types `Array` type matches, but I thought checking that something can `FETCH` or `STORE` would be the right match.

Comment: not sure what you're asking as you already know about `VAR`; at a lower level, there's also `nqp::iscont`, `nqp::isrwcont` and `nqp::iscont_[ins]` for native containers

Comment: Checking VAR doesn't seem to work. I'll revise the answer later.

Comment: Remember that arrays containerize their values. So in your example, every element of `@ab` is wrapped in a container no matter if it was wrapped in a container before you put it into `@ab`.

Comment: swap `my @ab=…` with `my \ab=…`  and you will see a different result.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you're asking here, but given your input, the output is as expected.

A simplified example for clarification:

```
my (@a, @b, @c);
my @ab = @a, @b, @c;

for @ab {
    say "{.^name} contained in a {.VAR.^name}";
}
```

which will output

```
Array contained in a Scalar
```

three times, no matter the contens of `@a`, `@b` and `@c`.

Remember, there's no implicit flattening in Perl6, and array mutbility (of non-native arrays) is realized by putting its elements in scalar containers.

---

Given the edit to your question, perhaps the following code will further clarify what's going on:

```
# make argument raw so binding won't mess with it
sub info($_ is raw) {
    dd $_;
    put "  value type: {.^name}";
    put "  VAR type: {.VAR.^name}";
    put "  can fetch: {so .VAR.can('FETCH')}";
    put "  can store: {so .VAR.can('STORE')}";
}

my \values = 42, my $ = 42, [1, 2], (1, 2);
info $_ for values;

put "\n";

# put values in array, which wraps them in a scalar container
info $_ for [values];
```

Note that only lists and arrays can `STORE` (but not `FETCH`), while scalars can do neither.

This might be a surprise: For one, we might have expected that anything assignable should provide a `STORE`.

Looking at the implementation, we see that for variables with sigil `@` and `%`, we [do call `STORE`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/acec1ea/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L6659..L6667), but [not so](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/acec1ea/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L6668..L6673) for variables with a `$` sigil. If we went further down the rabbit hole, we'd eventually end up at the [VM level container specification](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/src/6model/containers.h), which is how assignment to scalar containers (or the invocation of a `Proxy` object's `STORE` method) is implemented.

Comment: "As expected" is wasn't what I expected. :)

Comment: Are you sure about the "just a naming coincidence"? Arrays *can* be used on the left-hand side of an assignment, and in that sense they are containers. Isn't that what the STORE method does for both `Array` and `Proxy`?

Comment: @smls: yeah, I was wrong about that (I thought `STORE` for arrays and lists was involved with positional access, but looking at the code, it is indeed about assignment)